# default value of a unique_ptr

Tags: c++, gcc, unique-ptr

I am having difficulty understanding default value of unique_ptr.
From the [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) I see that there are two constructors of unique_ptr that says it owns *nothing*
 Does *nothing* mean *nullptr*?

```
constexpr unique_ptr() noexcept;
constexpr unique_ptr( std::nullptr_t ) noexcept;
```

I created an small example below. If I check for nullptr, it returns true. Is this behavior  guaranteed?

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class A {
  public:
    A(int i) :m_i(i) {}
    ~A() {}
    int getI() { return m_i; }
  private:
    int m_i;
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<A> a;
    if(a == nullptr) {
     std::cout << "A is null\n";   
    }
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> vec;
    vec.resize(5);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        if(vec[i] == nullptr) {
            std::cout << "Nullptr" << std::endl;   
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

O/p of the above code in my system (gcc) is

```
A is null
Nullptr
Nullptr
Nullptr
Nullptr
Nullptr
```

If I check for null on an uninitialized unique_ptr, is it guaranteed that it will be nullptr? Or Is it implementation defined?

Comment: nullptr is nullptr, not nothing. nullptr points to nothing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For these two constructor overloads:

```
constexpr unique_ptr() noexcept;
constexpr unique_ptr(std::nullptr_t) noexcept;
```

The [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) says that these two constructors above create a `std::unique_ptr` object that ***owns nothing***.

Now, by looking at the [documentation of `std::unique_ptr`'s `get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get) member function:

> Returns a pointer to the managed object or `nullptr` if no object is owned.

Since the `std::unique_ptr` objects that are created through any of those two constructors *own nothing*, we conclude that `get()` returns `nullptr` for these `std::unique_ptr` objects.

Answer (score 11):

*"nothing"* in this context means a non-owned state.

The pointer itself gets [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) (which for regular pointers results in a null pointer), see [[unique.ptr.single.ctor]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/unique.ptr#single.ctor-3):

> `constexpr unique_ptr() noexcept;`
> . . .
>
> 2 *Effects:* Constructs a `unique_ptr` object that owns nothing, ***value-initializing*** the stored pointer and the stored deleter.
>
> 3 *Postconditions:* **`get() == nullptr`**. `get_deleter()` returns a reference to the stored deleter.

So [`unique_ptr::get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get) is guaranteed to return `nullptr` for a non-owned state.